# Does a linear quotient map have sections

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

Suppose $V$ is a vector space with vector subspace $N$. Then there is 
a natural projection

$$
\pi_N: V \to V/N
$$

from the vector space $V$ to the quotient space $VN$ of $V$ modulo $N$. 
Does $\pi_N$ have sections?

Means are there 'section maps' $i: V/N \to V$ with $\pi_N\circ i=id_{V/N}$? I'm
not asking for a single natural inclusion map $i$ because, I know that in general
there is none, but I'm asking, if I can assume that there are **any** sections for
the proection $\pi_{V/N}$.

The question arose, since in other parts of mathematics similar sections are 
important (Bundle sections, retracts in homology ect.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 \to N \to V \to V/N \to0$ is exact and $V/N$ is a vector space,i.e. a module over a field thus it's free and a fortiori it's projective. This means that your exact sequence splits and this is equivalent to the existence of the section you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! A clean and conceptual answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Select a basis of $V/N$, for each basis vector select a preimage in $V$. Map accordingly.

Comment: Does this require $V$ or $V/N$ to be finite dimensional?

Comment: In ZFC none of them, otherwise (but I don't think it's your case) you need $V/N$ to be finite dimensional: but without the axiom of choice $V/N$ may have no basis, thus you need it.